# Solve dependency cycle issue in NextJS application

Tags: typescript, import, next.js, dependencies, circular-dependency

I am having an issue with a dependency cycle within my NextJS application that I am currently struggling to solve.

Here are my files. I have only included the imports which are showing depenency cycle error

store.ts:

```
import rootSaga from './sagas/rootSaga';import authSliceStore from './slices/auth/authSlice.store';
// Dependency cycle via ./auth/auth.saga    

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'ea-root',
  version: 1,
  storage,
  blacklist: ['authError'],
};

export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  auth: authSliceStore,
});

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
const middleware = [sagaMiddleware];

/**
 * Creates a store and includes all the slices as reducers.
 */
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: {
        ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
      },
    }).concat(middleware),
  devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
});

sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);

export const persistor = persistStore(store);

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
```

rootSaga.ts

```
import { all } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { loginSaga, logoutSaga } from './auth/auth.saga';
// Dependency cycle via ../../store


export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([
    loginSaga(),
    logoutSaga(),    
  ]);
}
```

auth.saga.ts

```
import { persistor } from '../../store';
// Dependency cycle via ./sagas/rootSaga

const isAxiosError = (x: any): x is AxiosError => {
  return x.isAxiosError === true;
};
  
export function* logUserOut() {
  Cookies.remove('access_token');
  Cookies.remove('leisureManagementToken');
  localStorage.removeItem('persist:ea-root');

  yield call(persistor.purge);
  yield call(Router.push, '/login');
}

function* loginSaga() {
  yield takeLatest('auth/loginRequested', makeLoginRequest);
}

function* logoutSaga() {
  yield takeLatest('auth/logout', logUserOut);
}

export { logoutSaga };
```

As you can see, this crude diagram is the issue as it stands:

[image]

Can anyone advise here? Thamks

Comment: You should check the redux-persist docs to make sure that what I am about to suggest is okay.  I believe that you can replace `yield call(persistor.purge);` with `yield put({ type: PURGE, result: () => null });` to dispatch the `PURGE` action from redux-persist directly.